# Get postback control in PageRequestManager endRequest event

Tags: asp.net, .net-4.0, asp.net-ajax

how could I get the ID of the control that caused the postback in the PageRequestManager endRequest event?

I looked at EndRequestEventArgs with Firebug but could not find such property. I am using .NET 4. Thank you.

Comment: Closely related/dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/596645

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is no “postback control ID” property in the “[endRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383810.aspx)” eventArgs, it is possible to capture the required data within the “[beginRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397432.aspx)” eventArgs and store it via temporary global variable.

Take a look at the “Example” of the “[Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager beginRequest Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397432.aspx)” MSDN topic to learn more on how to capture “postback control”.